# Image orientation in ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

In my application I get image URLs from web service and show them in ImageView. Some of the images are being shown rotated by 90, 180 or 270 degrees.

I have tried to get orientation from EXIF

```
ExifInterface exif = null;
try {
exif = new ExifInterface(path);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}  
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 
                                   ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
```

but this orientation is always 0. 
I also tried this

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, null, null, null);
```

but the cursor is being null.

So how can I get image orientation from it's path in server?
Thanks.

Comment: Please Follow the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726860/android-how-to-detect-the-image-orientation-portrait-or-landscape-picked-fro

Comment: @VishalRaj this is about an image picked from gallery. I want to load it from URL. Can't I get orientation any way?

Comment: Not if that info is not stored somewhere. I.e.: in the EXIF metadata.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein that info is stored in EXIF metadata. When I download the image manually and watch in properties I can see the rotation angle. But exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL) returns 0

Comment: The `Orientation` tag has only **8** possible values. No angle. The angle information is provided by the software, basing upon the value stored in the tag.

Comment: Yes, I was checking the rotation angle with a software.