# Weird behaviour canvas - Bitmap rotated by itself

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I'm creating a view that will allow me to draw over a given bitmap.

As I create the canvas I set the bitmap as the base for it. It works perfectly on an emulator but, when I try to use it on my phone it behave strangely and rotate the bitmap by 90 degrees.

Here is how I create the canvas. I get the right `backgroundPicture` from my previous activity.

```
    mBitmap = backgroundPicture.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, width, height, true);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
```

ANd here are the screenshots

When I take the picture : 
[image: When I take the picture]

What it displays in my recycler view (displays normally)
[image: recycler view display]

What it displays on the canvas (90 degrees on the left)
[image: weird display]

Thank you for your help, I'm not used to work with canvases so I'm a bit lost :/

Comment: Can you share the code that computes `width` & `height`?

Comment: Sure, here it is 
`public void init(DisplayMetrics metrics, Uri picUri) {
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    }`

Comment: It seems like the image orientation creates the problem. Perhaps you can check that and rotate the whole thing (replace width and height & rotate the canvas as you draw)

Comment: I thought about that but I can't understand why on the emulator it works just fine :/ That's what really bothering me, the huge difference in the behaviour on one device and another

Comment: I suggest you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726860/android-how-to-detect-the-image-orientation-portrait-or-landscape-picked-fro?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I tried to get the orientation of the image but it gives me a rotation value of 0. So if I believe my ExifInterface I have a rotated image that isn't "officialy" rotated :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging it appears that the problem comes from my smartphone, a **Samsung Galaxy** A3. In some **Samsung models the camera is rotated** to gain place for the others components of the phone. Some Samsung handle the difference but if they don't you'll get an **rotation of 0** and you'll have to **handle the rotation** problem model by model **manually**.

I hope this will help other people.

Cordially,
Matthieu