# Get orientation of URI image

Tags: java, android, image, kotlin

My app involves users choosing a photo from the gallery which then returns the `URI`. To upload this image onto my Firebase Google Storage I perform the following operations on the bitmap:

```
val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, baos)
val imgData = baos.toByteArray()
var uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(imgData)
```

This successfully compresses and uploads my image. However, many images are landscape and not portrait - therefore I have to account for this and rotate the bitmap accordingly before I upload.

I discovered the [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface) ([example of it here](https://github.com/google/cameraview/issues/22#issuecomment-269321811)) however it requires API level 24 and **my minimum API level is 21**.

How can I get the orientation of my image and then rotate it to portrait - with a method that will work on API level 21?

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726860/android-how-to-detect-the-image-orientation-portrait-or-landscape-picked-fro

Comment: `ExifInterface` does not required API-24 its added in API-5.. There maybe some method added later ..

Comment: This is how it looks in my Android Studio: https://i.imgur.com/S5skIa2.png is this an error?

Comment: Below API 24, you have to pass String path in ExifInterface

Comment: Follow this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726860/android-how-to-detect-the-image-orientation-portrait-or-landscape-picked-fro